# Installed Ubuntu due to Windows 7 failure, need to save windows data drive

Tags: mount, windows-7, lvm, partitioning, disk-management

I am a first time Ubuntu user.

I have installed Ubuntu due to my Windows 7 did not want to boot up (tried safe mode, command line, boot disk, boot from usb....etc. )

On my Windows 7 setup, I have the following Disk Partitions:
c: system
d: files
e: major data storage for important stuff

I have now installed ubuntu, and can wanting to get all my data out from e:, then format all 3 drives above.

My problem is, I cannot manage to get e: be mounted so far.
The format on the drive is not detected.

Can someone please guide me step by step how to rescue my files out?

Thank you very much.

---

### Added Notes from Comments

I installed ntfs as you suggested.

```
root@piggy-Ideapad-Z570:~# lvs 
LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Meta% Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert     
root ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 690.20g 
swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 7.91g



root@piggy-Ideapad-Z570:~# vgs

VG    #PV #LV #SN Attr VSize VFree 
ubuntu-vg 1 2 0 wz--n- 698.16g 40.00m

$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member' 


$ blkid 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="OldWindows" UUID="31C048F06C2BEECC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5118739f-01" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="k0mgvC-ioOZ-xyvt-1AoF-B5Gv-ZGCU-oPVvmD" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="429f849a-3e4f-41cc-ac78-873ec0fa11f6" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="50ddb2e6-62f4-4033-a255-b4e57b75c5f7" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/dm-1: UUID="50ddb2e6-62f4-4033-a255-b4e57b75c5f7" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: How do you mount it and what exact error you get?

Comment: root@piggy-Ideapad-Z570:~# lvs LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Meta% Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert root ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 690.20g swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 7.91g root@piggy-Ideapad-Z570:~# vgs VG #PV #LV #SN Attr VSize VFree ubuntu-vg 1 2 0 wz--n- 698.16g 40.00m I tried: sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/ I got: mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you've provided in the comments, your `/dev/sda5` partition is, in fact, an **LVM** partition.  Therefore, please don't try to mount it as you would a non-LVM partition.

This is the `blkid` output you provided, and stubbornly refused to add to the question by ignoring my instructions to do so:

```
blkid 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="OldWindows" UUID="31C048F06C2BEECC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5118739f-01" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="k0mgvC-ioOZ-xyvt-1AoF-B5Gv-ZGCU-oPVvmD" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="429f849a-3e4f-41cc-ac78-873ec0fa11f6" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="50ddb2e6-62f4-4033-a255-b4e57b75c5f7" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/dm-1: UUID="50ddb2e6-62f4-4033-a255-b4e57b75c5f7" TYPE="swap"
```

I will assume your `pvs` output will show the `/dev/sda5` partition designated as the **Physical Volume Disk**, upon which the `ubuntu--vg` **Volume Group** is located.  The Volume Group appears to have *two* **Logical Volume** partitions:

1. root
2. swap

If this is the case, then the `/dev/sda5` partition is already mounted as the main `/` partition of your Ubuntu installation!

Once again, please provide as much information as you can ***within the actual question***.

The output of the `mount`, `fdisk -l`, `pvs`, and perhaps the `df -Th` commands would be of particular use to anyone attempting to diagnose the problem you claim to have with the partition.

Please see the [Ubuntu Wiki: LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) page for more information on LVM in Ubuntu.

---

### Initial Erroneous Assumption of Windows Partition in Use

I will assume that the Windows partition is formatted as **NTFS**, like most other Windows partitions.

Since you say you're a "first-time Ubuntu user", I will assume that you don't have the necessary tools installed to work with ntfs partitions.  If I recall correctly, mainly the `ntfs-3g` program needs to be installed.  Therefore, execute in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Are you experiencing the same problems with the other Windows partitions as well?

If your drive is, for some reason, formatted as a "vfat" partition, you may also need the **vfat** driver installed.  Note, this partition type is primarily used on windows-compatible removable devices, e.g. USB drives.

Please take a look at the [Community Wiki: Mounting Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions).

Comment: I installed ntfs as you suggested.

root@piggy-Ideapad-Z570:~# lvs
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 690.20g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao----   7.91g                                                    
root@piggy-Ideapad-Z570:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  ubuntu-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 698.16g 40.00m

I tried: sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/
I got:     mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Comment: root@piggy-Ideapad-Z570:~# blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="OldWindows" UUID="31C048F06C2BEECC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5118739f-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="k0mgvC-ioOZ-xyvt-1AoF-B5Gv-ZGCU-oPVvmD" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="429f849a-3e4f-41cc-ac78-873ec0fa11f6" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="50ddb2e6-62f4-4033-a255-b4e57b75c5f7" TYPE="swap"
/dev/dm-1: UUID="50ddb2e6-62f4-4033-a255-b4e57b75c5f7" TYPE="swap"

The one in LVM2_member is the one I wanted to mount

Comment: That's probably the Windows backup utility thing, which resembles LVM2; I'm not sure if it *is* LVM2, per se.  Once again, the [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) to the rescue.  By the way, try to add more specific info in your question, as someone suggested in the comment.  That error, for example, is a wealth of information. :D

Comment: Wait a minute.  I thought you said the partition was part of Windows.  That `blkid` output shows it's part of the `ubuntu--vg` volume group.

Comment: If you type `mount` in a terminal; better yet, `mount |grep ubuntu`, what is displayed?  Or, simply paste the output of `mount` into your question.

Comment: I no longer have Windows on my machine... when Win7 crashed, I installed Ubuntu and formatted Windows system drive.... that partition was created in Windows long ago, now containing all my important data

Comment: root@piggy-Ideapad-Z570:~# mount |grep ubuntu
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)

Comment: what's shown when you execute `pvs`? Also, please **Edit the Question and add the output to the question**.  Please also show the entire `mount` output.